# Android SQLiteException: no such column: -1

Tags: android, sqlite

One of my android apps performs the following specific SQLite query:

```
SELECT _id, hourMin, actions FROM profiles
WHERE type=2 AND hourMin > -1 AND days & 8 != 0 AND prof_id >> 16 IN (256)
ORDER BY hourMin ASC LIMIT 1
```

Now that works on some Android phones, but on a few of them it crashes with the following error:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: -1: , while
compiling: SELECT _id, hourMin, actions FROM profiles WHERE type=2 AND
hourMin > -1 AND days & 8 != 0 AND prof_id >> 16 IN (256) ORDER BY hourMin
ASC LIMIT 1
```

For some reason, "-1" is interpreted as a column rather than a number... that doesn't make much sense and when I read the SQLite query language I see no need to escape this number in parentheses. Could it be an issue of a different version of SQLite? Would adding parentheses this help any? Instead, I'll probably rewrite it using >= 0 but still I'd like to understand what's going on.

Comment: Try wrapping it in parentheses and see if it helps any. It may be an issue with grouping in the statement or something. If I were you, I would figure out the version number of sqlite on each phone so you had a point of comparison.

Comment: Yep that's what I'll do but it's a random shot. I like to understand my fixes :-)

Unfortunately I get some reports from users, I don't have access to the phones myself. It's actually hard for a user to even guess which SQLite version their phone has. Can't really ask them to setup ADB on their phone, install the SDK on their desktop, connect their phone via USB and run some cryptic command-line... :-)

Comment: I don't know which versions of SQLite even might be running on Android, so I won't hazard this as anything more than a comment. But I see from the change log that bitwise operators did not always exist. It's easy to imagine that particular error if the parser does not recognize the bitwise operators in the statement. Also, the precedence of ~ was fixed in 3.5.3. Again, I do not know, but I can imagine that a precedence error with ~ would also exist with negation (unlikely but not completely out of the question).

Comment: I also got a no such column exception even though the column clearly did exist. Turns out that Froyo didn't like columns with no data, so I just put a "1" in the field as a dummy, and it worked. Maybe that will help someone

Answer (score 0):

The way to test if the problem is caused by different versions of SQLite with different versions of Android without access to the actual phones is to create several emulator images for the different Android platforms.

This is quick and easy to do with the `android` GUI tool and will allow you to see if the problem occurs on different versions of Android and look at the log files if it does.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you table is created and non-empty before performing a SELECT query. Generally a column : -1 error is cause due to an empty table.

Try this code if you want to check for creation of table:

```
  Cursor c = dbObject.rawQuery(....some query....);
  try{
    c.moveToFirst(); //checking for non-empty table
  }
  catch(Exception e){       // in case table is empty
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    //add some default table entries
  }
```

After this if you reference the table you will not get any column : -1 error.